# How to store eli5 fig in HTML or in Google BigQuery

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-bigquery

How to store eli5 predicted values in HTML or in Google BigQuery.
Using this part of code:

```
pred = eli5.show_prediction(lr_model.named_steps["model"], X_test.iloc[[i]],feature_names=num_features, show_feature_values=True)
```

[image: pred eli5 fig]

Answer (score 0):

As you are using pandas, I suggest that you use [pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html) to store your values into Cloud BigQuery ([example from GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#loading_a_pandas_dataframe_to_a_table)).

```
dataframe.to_gbq('YourBQdataset.Yourtable',... )
```